# Importing a test suite into another project in soapUI

Tags: soapui, functional-testing

I am working on a evaluation automation scenario in which i will create a test suite on one project-1 in soapUI and import into other projects (project2,project3) where the same test cases are applicable.

I exported the test suite and imported it in new project.But problem is,after importing into project2 and updating the test suite with new request, still the process request in the test case of test suite is having the end point URL of the project-1.How can this be rectified and also please point me source or documentation of how to import and export test suites.
Exporting test suite contains:

1.TestCase under which are:

```
1.Property File
2.Property Transfer
3.Process(of project-1)
```

SoapUI version-5.2.1

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is not just enough to copy the test suites, also respective services wsdls must be available in the target project as well. Why are you complicating?

Comment: @Rao The service wsdls of project-1 and project-2(where i am importing testcase) are having the same definitions inside the xml but with different endpoints.Will that affect? if yes,then please suggest me an alternate solution to test the scenario.All i want to do is to evaluate certain scripts of other implementers who has done the requirement by using the testsuite i created for my implementation.

Comment: If you copy the artifacts from one project to others, then how would other project be different. Isn't it like as if you do file copy of project 1 to 2,3 and on, why to write groovy for that? Clarify otherwise?

Comment: Can i write groovy for that? I am beginner so cant think of any ways to do the testing automation.